# Return a generic, implicit reference

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
public class Display<T> where T : class, IDisplay<T>
{
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public Display(List<T> myList, int total)
    {
        MyList = myList;
        Total = total;
    }
}

public interface IDisplay<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> MyList { get; set; }
    int Total { get; set; }
}


MyClass() : IMyClass
{
}

public interface IMyClass
{
}
```

When I use :

```
return new Display<IMyClass>(listOffIMyClass, anIntValue);
```

I get this error :
*IMyClass cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Display'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IMyClass' to 'IMyClass'.*

Comment: You're probably misreading the error message: It should say _There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IMyClass' to 'IDisplay<IMyClass>'._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, yes - you've said that the `T` used for a `Display<T>` has to implement `IDisplay<T>`, and `IMyClass` doesn't implement `IDisplay<IMyClass>`.

Did you *actually* just mean to make `Display<T>` implement `IDisplay<T>`? If so, you want:

```
public class Display<T> : IDisplay<T> where T : class
```

Now you're still constraining `T` to be a reference type, but you're *not* constraining `T` to implement `IDisplay<T>`.